# Retrieve/get nested node objects from firebase realtime using kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the data objects (address, check_in, check_out) from the date which is in the nested node.

My database goes by like this:

```
---`attendance` :{
   |
   |---danielle:{ <---------- here is username, node of `attendance`
   |   |
   |   |---2023-04-08: <----------- here is the date she checked in and out for work
   |   |   |
   |   |   |---address: "Thomas street"
   |   |   |
   |   |   |---check_in: "09:02 AM"
   |   |   |
   |   |   |---check_out: "06:30 PM"
   |   |
   |   |
   |    ---2023-04-10":
   |       |
   |       |---address: "Maria street"
   |       |
   |       |---check_in: "09:02 AM"
   |       |
   |        ---check_out: "06:30 PM"
   |
    ---mark:{ <---------- here is another username
       |
       |---2023-04-07: <----------- here is the date he checked in and out for work
       |   |
       |   |---address: "Thomas street"
       |   |
       |   |---check_in: "09:02 AM"
       |   |
       |   |---check_out: "06:30 PM"
       |
       |
        ---2023-04-11":
           |
           |---address: "Maria street"
           |
           |---check_in: "10:23 AM"
           |
            ---check_out: "08:30 PM"
```

I tried to use this coding

```
val attModel = arrayListOf<AttendanceModel>()

Firebase.database.getReference("Attendance").child("danielle").child("2023-04-08").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    for (h in snapshot.children) {
                        val data = h.getValue(AttendanceModel::class.java)

                        attModel.add(data!!)

                    }
                }
            }
```

but i get this error

```
Android : com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to AttendanceModel
```

I know `danielle` is indeed a `String`, but I don't understand how it can get an error because `danielle` has an object node inside.

I also tried this coding here where I tried to nest for the path `2023-04-08`

```
val todays = arrayListOf<AttendanceModel>()

        Firebase.database.getReference("Attendance").child("danielle")
            .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    for (h in snapshot.children) {
                        val date = h.child("2023-04-08")
                        for (i in date.children) {
                            val dataUser = i.getValue(AttendanceModel::class.java)

                            todays.add(dataUser!!)
                        }
```

In emulator doesnt return anything, and then i tried to log `dataUser`, it gives me

```
DataSnapshot { key = danielle, value = null }
```

Here is my data class

```
data class AttendanceModel(
    val loc_name: String? = "",
    val address: String? = "",
    val check_in: String? = "",
    val check_out: String? = ""
)
```

Any kind of help would be so much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attach a listener on the `2023-04-08`, there is no need for an iteration, you can directly read the values of the children, or you can map the node into an object of type `AttendanceModel`. In code, it will be as simple as:

```
val db = Firebase.database.reference
val dateRef = db.child("attendance/danielle/2023-04-08")
dateRef.get().addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        val snapshot = it.result
        val key = snapshot.key
        Log.d(TAG, "key: $key")
        val data = snapshot.getValue(AttendanceModel::class.java)
        Log.d(TAG, "data: ${data.address}${data.check_in}/${data.check_out}")
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "${it.exception?.message}") //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
}
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
key: 2023-04-08
data: Thomas street/09:02 AM/06:30 PM
```

Comment: Hey Adela. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

No need iteration snapshot children because already entire object fetch for date. If we use iteration, it's will return value for each key which inside the object.

Replace

```
for (h in snapshot.children) {
val data = h.getValue(AttendanceModel::class.java)
 attModel.add(data!!)
 }
```

by

```
 val data = snapshot.getValue(AttendanceModel::class.java)
            attModel.add(data!!)
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried replacing the code. And I get null error. I also tried to log `data`, returning null.